# Globally set custom HTTP header in AngularJS from ngInit

Tags: javascript, http, rest, angularjs, basic-authentication

I am unable to set custom HTTP header taken from `ngInit` in AngularJS.

I set variable using ngInit in html:

```
<div ng-init="myApiKey='valueOfVar'"></div>
```

Now I want to use this variable in all HTTP requests. I tried to set it in app.config and in controller too.

- If I set it immediately, variable is undefined.
- If I set it in `$scope.$watch` callback function, variable is
  defined, but HTTP requests are without that header.

I set header with:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'something';
```

(or via `$httpProvider`, when in app.config) and then use it in service utilizing `$resource`. My code looks like [this][1]

I tried to set it in `config`, in `run`, in controller and as a service, but nothing worked for me yet. Thank you in advance for any advice given.

**Edit:**
Now I have interceptor:

```
myApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
});

myApp.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        request: function($config) {
            $config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.apiKey;
            return $config;
        }
    };
}]);
```

But `$rootscope.apiKey` (which is set in main controller) is `undefined` at first call. After that, it's okay (and set).

Comment: Why not set it in the server side?

Comment: @Fals How? If I want to use that variable in Angular, then it has to be set in its js files, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so for anybody trying to do the same - **Interceptors** were the key (thank you **Fals** a lot), but problem was with the `$rootScope`. As I wrote in question, when Interceptor was called the first time, `$rootScope.apiKey` wasn't set yet (on consecutive requests, it was already set).

Right way (or *The working way*) was to pass variable to AngularJS not through `ngInit`, but through `$window`. So I added to my HTML code:

```
<script>window.apiKey = 'myValue';</script>
```

and then pass it to Interceptor exactly the same way as `$rootScope` - You can literally just replace all occurences of `$rootScope` in edit of my question with `$window` and now it's working - even for the first request!

Thank you Fals once again.

Answer (score 4):

the following code will allow you to intercept all http  requestes of your application
and to add a property 'language' in the header of the request

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']).run(function($http) {
  $http.defaults.headers.common.language='fr-FR';
});
```

we can add many properties in the http header

Answer (score 3):

If you wanna modify request/response in AngularJS you should do a deeply read about **Interceptor**:

- Angular JS Web Site: [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

You can call $http(config), where config is a object with every configuration. There's a configuration there for `headers`, where you should put your code:

> headers – {Object} – Map of strings or functions which return strings representing HTTP 
>   headers to send to the server. If the return value of a function is
>   null, the header will not be sent.

If you google about Interceptor, you will get a full list of blogs explaining how to use It, and providing example codes, here's one that help me out sometime ago:

[Understanding angular $http interceptors](http://djds4rce.wordpress.com/2013/08/13/understanding-angular-http-interceptors/)

Comment: Thank you. I'm almost there, but I can't get my `$scope` into interceptor, so I could take that variable from it (from the `$scope`). When I put it as an argument to request function (with `$config` - which works okay) it's `undefined`.

Comment: OK - now I finally succeeded in injecting $rootScope in, my variable is set, but not for the first time, the interceptor is called. First HTTP request is without auth header, but others are okay. Don't you know, how to make it work even for the first time?